# Why is sudo taking a long time to execute

Tags: linux, sudo, redhat-enterprise-linux

When running commands with sudo it always takes about 4 or 5 seconds for the command to run even something as simple as `echo test`.

I am running rhel 9.

After looking at some other question I ran `sudo strace -t -f sudo echo`.
When doing so I get the following, I am guessing this is the issue but not sure what is causing this.

```
[pid 318837] 17:15:24 close(11)         = 0
[pid 318837] 17:15:24 prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, NULL, {rlim_cur=512*1024, rlim_max=512*1024}) = 0
[pid 318837] 17:15:24 close(65535)      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid 318837] 17:15:24 close(65534)      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid 318837] 17:15:24 close(65533)      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid 318837] 17:15:24 close(65532)      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid 318837] 17:15:24 close(65531)      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid 318837] 17:15:24 close(65530)      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid 318837] 17:15:24 close(65529)      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid 318837] 17:15:24 close(65528)      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid 318837] 17:15:24 close(65527)      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid 318837] 17:15:24 close(65526)      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)


# this continues counting down by 1 each time


[pid 318837] 17:15:26 close(14)         = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid 318837] 17:15:26 close(13)         = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid 318837] 17:15:26 close(12)         = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid 318837] 17:15:26 close(11)         = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
[pid 318837] 17:15:26 close(10)         = 0
[pid 318837] 17:15:26 close(9)          = 0
[pid 318837] 17:15:26 close(8)          = 0
[pid 318837] 17:15:26 close(7)          = 0
[pid 318837] 17:15:26 close(6)          = 0
[pid 318837] 17:15:26 close(5)          = 0
[pid 318837] 17:15:26 close(4)          = 0
[pid 318837] 17:15:26 close(3)          = 0
[pid 318837] 17:15:26 geteuid()         = 0
[pid 318837] 17:15:26 setuid(0)         = 0
```